# Add Multiple documents along with collection to firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Basically i am trying to have a multiple Hierarchy on inserting data into firestore.

This is the blueprint of the firestore database i am having

[image: Image 1]

[image]

The Code what I have written is

```
if(message != ""){
            var docId = '';
            var room = db.collection("rooms");
            db.collection("rooms").add({
                name : 'demo',
                room_type : 0
            })
            .then(function(docRef) {
                $(".message-input").val("");
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
                room.doc(docRef.id).collection.add({message : message,
                timestamp : '',
                user : '',
                userImage : ''});
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });
        }
```

Here the first document is being succesfully inserted but the next document i am trying to insert is not happening. Any help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `collection name`.
It should be `db.collection("rooms").doc(docRef.id).collection(collection_name).add(...)`

```
if(message != ""){
            var docId = '';
            var room = db.collection("rooms");
            db.collection("rooms").add({
                name : 'demo',
                room_type : 0
            })
            .then(function(docRef) {
                $(".message-input").val("");
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
                db.collection("rooms").doc(docRef.id).collection(collection_name).add({message : message,
                timestamp : '',
                user : '',
                userImage : ''});
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });
        }
```